# Popularity sorting doesnt work

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation, filter, sorting

I recently installed **FME layered navigation**. Now my toolbar sorting doesn't work right. When it loads, everything is correct. It sorts by the standard "**most viewed**", but when i change sorting to newest and then back to most viewed again, it doesn't work.. it just shows some other products, almost like if there was no sorting.

Anyone got any clue how i can fix this? its only a problem for the most viewed sorting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i cannot give you whole solution on that but you have tweak this file to make it because fme layered navigation will work with default sorting.

**app/code/local/FME/Layerednav/Block/List.php**

check this method `setListOrders`

hope it will help you.